# How to allow user to view and run one single DAG in UI

Tags: airflow, rbac

I have just created a new user with a new role. I want to allow that user to enter the UI, login, click on the DAG, and once in the Graph View, let him/her trigger the DAG and see the task's status. I have granted the role the following permissions:

```
can read on My Profile
can read on View Menus
menu access on Views/Menus
can create on DAG Runs
can read on DAG Runs
can create on Task Instances
can read on Task instances
can read on Website
can read on DAG:X
can edit on DAG:X
```

But when I try to enter the DAG logged as this new user, I get access denied. I am using Airflow 2.1.2. Which permission should I add?